# How to find ACK for multiple segments using Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to use Wireshark to find a ACK (for TCP connections) send my the server which ACKs multiple segments as opposed to just ACKing 1 segment.

Is there a wireshark filter than can help me with this rather than manually going through the list and finding a packet where the server has ACK'd 2 or more segments.

Comment: Filters are applied to individual packets, but what you are asking for can only be decided by considering multiple packets in the flow. So to achieve this, you would need to filter on the annotations Wireshark attach to the packets on loading. There are information related to ACKs such as `tcp.analysis.acks_frame`, `tcp.analysis.bytes_in_flight`, and `tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack`. But I found nothing which I think could answer your question. You can type `tcp.analysis.` and look if any of the suggested completions sounds useful.

Comment: @kasperd Yes I think I need to filter unwanted packets and monitor it myself.